# No results in scraping bing search

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i use code below to scrape results from bing and when I see the scraped web page it says "There are no results for python".
but when I search in the browser there is no problem.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

term = 'python'
url = f'https://www.bing.com/search?q={term}&setlang=en-us'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

I searched and I didn't find any similar problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `user-agent` while requesting to get the value.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

term = 'python'
url = 'https://www.bing.com/search?q={}&setlang=en-us'.format(term)
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because there's no `user-agent` being passed into request `headers` (as already mentioned by [KunduK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63119504/15164646)) thus when no `user-agent` is specified while using `requests` library, it defaults to [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) so Bing or other search engines understands that it's a bot/script, then it blocks a request. Check [what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

Pass `user-agent`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}

requests.get('URL', headers=headers)
```

[How to reduce the chance of being blocked while web scraping search engines](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/how-to-reduce-chance-being-blocked-while-web-scraping-search-engines-1o46).

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Bing Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/bing-organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that you don't have to spend time trying to bypass blocks from Bing or other search engines. Instead, focus on the data that needs to be extracted from the structured JSON. Check out the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score 0):

Since Bing is a dynamic website, meaning Javascript generates the code, you won't be able to scrape it using only Beautifulsoup. Instead, I recommend [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/), which opens a browser that you can control and parse the code with Beautifulsoup.

The same will happen for any other dynamically coded website, including Google and many others.